# How can add all UIButton in UITableView to NSArray in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I want to add all `UIButton viewwithTag :4000` (below code) in `UITableView` to array. How can i do that? Please give me any suggestions .
 this is my code create uitableview :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *identifier = @"identifier";
    cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    UIButton *market = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
        [market setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 6, 30, 30)];
        market.tag = 4000;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:market]; 

   }

    UIButton *marketButton = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4000];
    [marketButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    if([sellingArray count]>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"sellingArray %@",sellingArray);
        if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]) // nothing
        {
            [marketButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Marketplace.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        else if([[sellingArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"2"])  // marketplace
        {
            [marketButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MarketplaceSelect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
    }
    [marketButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    } 
    }
return cell;
}
```

I want to change image of Marketbutton when reloadData, but it can not change so I want to add all Marketbutton to array, then set image for each button. Please help me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray* myButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

...

[myButtons addObject: marketButton];
```

Comment: NSMutableArray* myButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; at - (void)viewDidLoad ofc or at - (id)initWithNibName if you want

Comment: i tried your code but it show error : [__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: i put [myButtons addObject: marketButton]; in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: sorry I do not provide a code ready for copy-paste to your environment, for free, if you can't use it, you don't deserve it

Answer (score 0):

**In viewDidLoad**

```
myButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

**Inside if condition**

```
if(cell == nil){
...
[myButtons addObject: marketButton];
}
```